# Assistance requested with date display

Tags: java, time

So, I have some code that determines the date by doing a whole bunch of stuffs with the `System.currentTimeMillis();` statement. However, I have been having issues with the code, and although I can make it display the month and date correctly, the year is always 2 years ahead (ex: if it's 1970, my code will display 1972, etc...). Although it would be easier to just insert a statement subtracting 2 years from the calculated year, I wanted it to calculate the year reliably. But alas, I cannot find the issue that is causing this bug. If anyone can help me out with this, it would be greatly appreciated. Code is below.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class fancyClock {
public static void main(String[] args) {
int counter = 1;
int year = 1970;
boolean isLeapYear = false;
int yearsUntilLeapYear = 2;
int days = 0;
int daysTemp = 0;
int months = 1;
String month = "";
int hours = 24;
int minutes = 00;
int day = 0;


long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println(millis);

while (counter == 1) {
  if (millis - 86400000 > 0) {
     days++;
     millis = millis - 86400000;
  } else {
     counter--;
  }
}
counter++;
daysTemp = days;
while (counter == 1) {
   year++;
   yearsUntilLeapYear--;
if (yearsUntilLeapYear == 0) {
   isLeapYear = true;
}
  // ESSENTIAL!!! IF COND MUST BE MOD, NOT MINUS!!!
  if (daysTemp % 365 > 0 && isLeapYear == false) {
     daysTemp = daysTemp - 365;
  } else if (daysTemp % 366 > 0 && isLeapYear == true) {
     isLeapYear = false;
     yearsUntilLeapYear = 4;
     daysTemp = daysTemp - 366;
  } else {
     counter--;
  }
}
counter++;
if (isLeapYear == true) {
   daysTemp = daysTemp + 366;
} else if (isLeapYear == false) {
   daysTemp = daysTemp + 365;
}
System.out.println("Days after flip: " + daysTemp);

while (counter == 1) {
   if ((months == 1 && (daysTemp - 31 > 0)) || (months == 3 && (daysTemp - 31 > 0)) || (months == 5 && (daysTemp - 31 > 0)) || (months == 7 && (daysTemp - 31 > 0)) || (months == 8 && (daysTemp - 31 > 0)) || (months == 10 && (daysTemp - 31 > 0)) || (months == 12 && (daysTemp - 31 > 0))) {
     daysTemp = daysTemp - 31;
     months++;
  } else if (months == 2 && isLeapYear == true && (daysTemp - 29 > 0)) {
     daysTemp = daysTemp - 29;
     months++;
  } else if (months == 2 && isLeapYear == false && (daysTemp - 28 > 0)) {
     daysTemp = daysTemp - 28;
     months++;
  } else if ((months == 4 && (daysTemp - 30 > 0)) || (months == 6 && (daysTemp - 30 > 0)) || (months == 9 && (daysTemp - 30 > 0)) || (months == 11 && (daysTemp - 30 > 0))) {
     daysTemp = daysTemp - 30;
     months++;
  } else {
     counter--;
  }
}

if (months == 1) {
   month = "January";
} else if (months == 2) {
   month = "Febuary";
} else if (months == 3) {
   month = "March";
} else if (months == 4) {
   month = "April";
} else if (months == 5) {
   month = "May";
} else if (months == 6) {
   month = "June";
} else if (months == 7) {
   month = "July";
} else if (months == 8) {
   month = "August";
} else if (months == 9) {
   month = "September";
} else if (months == 10){
   month = "October";
} else if (months == 11){
   month = "November";
} else {
   month = "December";
}
day = daysTemp;


System.out.println("FANCY CLOCK BETA");
System.out.println("Current date: " + month + " " + day + ", " + year);


}
}
```

Comment: well I do not understand your logic at all. `while (counter == 1) {
   year++;`

Comment: It's just a normal loop. Keeps the code running until everything has been processed by the code.

Comment: @gnimmargorP make sure your class name follows PascalCase and not camelCase. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PascalCase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Few changes that I did to make it working:

- Your day displayed was incorrect as it was initialized with 0, it should be 1 as we have start from 1/1/1970
- As you want to consider the 1970 year in calculation you will have to initialize year with 1969 so that you consider 1970 in you calc logic.
- Also the year++ should happen only when the daysTemp mets criteria of 365 or 366 days.

I made these changes in the below code and ran it with the output as :

```
Days after flip: 67
FANCY CLOCK BETA
Current date: March 8, 2017
```

Code Here:

```
public class fancyClock {
public static void main(String[] args) {
int counter = 1;
int year = 1969;
boolean isLeapYear = false;
int yearsUntilLeapYear = 2;
int days = 1;
int daysTemp = 0;
int months = 1;
String month = "";
int hours = 24;
int minutes = 00;
int day = 0;

long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println(millis);


while (counter == 1) {
  if (millis - 86400000 > 0) {
     days++;
     millis = millis - 86400000;
  } else {
     counter--;
  }
}
counter++;
daysTemp = days;
while (counter == 1) {
if (yearsUntilLeapYear == 0) {
   isLeapYear = true;
}
  // ESSENTIAL!!! IF COND MUST BE MOD, NOT MINUS!!!
  if (daysTemp % 365 > 0 && isLeapYear == false) {
     daysTemp = daysTemp - 365;
     year++;
     yearsUntilLeapYear--;
  } else if (daysTemp % 366 > 0 && isLeapYear == true) {
     isLeapYear = false;
     yearsUntilLeapYear = 4;
     daysTemp = daysTemp - 366;
     year++;
     yearsUntilLeapYear--;
  } else {
     counter--;
  }
}
counter++;
if (isLeapYear == true) {
   daysTemp = daysTemp + 366;
} else if (isLeapYear == false) {
   daysTemp = daysTemp + 365;
}
System.out.println("Days after flip: " + daysTemp);

while (counter == 1) {
   if ((months == 1 && (daysTemp - 31 > 0)) || (months == 3 && (daysTemp - 31 > 0)) || (months == 5 && (daysTemp - 31 > 0)) || (months == 7 && (daysTemp - 31 > 0)) || (months == 8 && (daysTemp - 31 > 0)) || (months == 10 && (daysTemp - 31 > 0)) || (months == 12 && (daysTemp - 31 > 0))) {
     daysTemp = daysTemp - 31;
     months++;
  } else if (months == 2 && isLeapYear == true && (daysTemp - 29 > 0)) {
     daysTemp = daysTemp - 29;
     months++;
  } else if (months == 2 && isLeapYear == false && (daysTemp - 28 > 0)) {
     daysTemp = daysTemp - 28;
     months++;
  } else if ((months == 4 && (daysTemp - 30 > 0)) || (months == 6 && (daysTemp - 30 > 0)) || (months == 9 && (daysTemp - 30 > 0)) || (months == 11 && (daysTemp - 30 > 0))) {
     daysTemp = daysTemp - 30;
     months++;
  } else {
     counter--;
  }
}

if (months == 1) {
   month = "January";
} else if (months == 2) {
   month = "Febuary";
} else if (months == 3) {
   month = "March";
} else if (months == 4) {
   month = "April";
} else if (months == 5) {
   month = "May";
} else if (months == 6) {
   month = "June";
} else if (months == 7) {
   month = "July";
} else if (months == 8) {
   month = "August";
} else if (months == 9) {
   month = "September";
} else if (months == 10){
   month = "October";
} else if (months == 11){
   month = "November";
} else {
   month = "December";
}
day = daysTemp;


System.out.println("FANCY CLOCK BETA");
System.out.println("Current date: " + month + " " + day + ", " + year);


}
}
```